# Flask-Sqlalchemy many-to-one on same model

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm developing a website with dashboard which admins and moderators can create users. I want to separate users created by moderator and admin. Moderator can only edit the users that him/her created but admin can edit all the users.

I created my user model like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, ResourceMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # User details
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(24)) 
    address = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False,
                      server_default='')
    password = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, server_default='')

    # Relationships
    created_id = db.Column(db.Integer, 
                       db.ForeignKey('users.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='SET NULL'),
                       index=True)
    updated_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                       db.ForeignKey('users.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='SET NULL'),
                       index=True)
```

Most of the situations this code works like charm. But when moderator or admin tries to edit self, program throws CircularDependency error. What might cause the problem?

Thanks